# I have a problem about bibliography when build `.tex`

Tags: biography

In the Visual Studio Code with LaTeX-Workshop, the built pdf cannot contain the bibliography. However, in the TeXworks, the .tex file can be successfully compiled. In the Visual Code, the compiler log only show two errors but not indicate what exactly the errors are.

There is the log of compiler.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: ieeetr.bst
Database file #1: refs.bib
I was expecting an "="---line 967 of file refs.bib
 :   
 :   author={G. {Zhao} and K. {Xu} and L. {Xu} and B. {Wu}}, 
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 987 of file refs.bib
 : @misc{liu2018large
 :                   ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--empty year in nasrcomprehensive
Warning--empty year in melis2019exploiting
Warning--empty year in wang2019beyond
Warning--empty year in truex2018hybrid
Warning--empty booktitle in huang2008labeled
Warning--empty year in ateniese2013hacking
Warning--empty year in ganju2018property
Warning--empty year in song2017machine
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: It's not necessary to encase the surnames of authors' names in the `author` field in curly braces.

Comment: What's in the two lines immediately before the `author={G. {Zhao} and K. {Xu} and L. {Xu} and B. {Wu}}, ` line?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see.

For the beginning, try to remove double defined reference

@misc{liu2018large